# Default implementations for protocols and associated types

Tags: swift

I get a really strange behaviour as I follow the steps of protocol-orientated-programming and default implementations.
I have a protocol, now called `TestProtocol`, with the following implemenation

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    init()
    func test1()
    func test2()
}
```

and an implementation of that protocol, now called `TestClass`:

```
struct TestClass : TestProtocol {
    init() {}
    func test1() { print("test1") }
    func test2() { print("test2") }
}
```

I want to use this class in a datastructure called `Datastructure`, which can take elements of a `TestProtocol`. so I wrote an protocol with a default implementation and an implementation:

```
protocol DatastructureProtocol {
    typealias ElementType: TestProtocol
}

extension DatastructureProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        ElementType().test1()
        ElementType().test2()
    }
}

struct Datastructure<T: TestProtocol> : DatastructureProtocol {
    typealias ElementType = T
    init() {}
}
```

I don't know if that code is complete garbage. If so, please don't hesitate to correct me. The funny part is, that the `doSomething` method doesn't call the right methods. It prints

```
test2
test1
```

which clearly isn't the right order. It seems like the default implementation maps the function calls to the wrong implementations. I have no idea why. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rusty1s

Comment: Not able to replicate your error. [Here's the swiftstub.](http://swiftstub.com/541043345/?v=beta)

Comment: Same thing for me.  Does not reproduce.  Are you sure you posted exactly the same code that you use?

Comment: Yeah you are right, tested it by myself. I wrote a much simpler version of my program and thought the same behaviour would occur. I will look into it and post here when I can reproduce the error.